# Looping through a dictionary<int, int[]> and getting unexpected results

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, switch-statement

I have been working with C# and Visual Studio creating an app to assist with my Game Mastering.
Working on this part of the app, I am having trouble getting the answer I expect.

I have tried several different methods of giving the "weights" including (current) `Dictionary<int, int[]>`, jaggered array, multiple arrays, and I've found that a Dictionary is going to be simplest.

I'm expecting that when I click a button, it runs the following code to produce ONE result, but I am getting anywhere from 3-5 results.

`challenge1_click` is the button click event:

```
private void challenge1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<int, int[]> weights = new Dictionary<int, int[]>() {
        { 30, new int[]{5,0,0,0,0}},
        { 60, new int[]{0,4,0,0,0}},
        { 70, new int[]{0,0,3,0,0}},
        { 95, new int[]{0,0,0,3,0}},
        { 100,new int[]{0,0,0,0,1}}
    };
    Random one = new Random();
    Random two = new Random();
    int d100 = RollDice(100, one);
    int[] results = IndividualTreasure(weights, d100);
    TreasureResults(results);
}

private int[] IndividualTreasure(Dictionary<int, int[]> weights, int d100)
{
    int cp = 0, sp = 0, gp = 0, ep = 0, pp = 0;
    Random num = new Random();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int[]> entry in weights)
    {
        if (d100 <= entry.Key)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < entry.Value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (entry.Value[i] > 0)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            for (int j = 0; j < entry.Value[i]; j++)
                            {
                                int randNum = RollDice(6, num);
                                cp += randNum;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            for (int j = 0; j < entry.Value[i]; j++)
                            {
                                int randNum = RollDice(6, num);
                                sp += randNum;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            for (int j = 0; j < entry.Value[i]; j++)
                            {
                                int randNum = RollDice(6, num);
                                gp += randNum;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            for (int j = 0; j < entry.Value[i]; j++)
                            {
                                int randNum = RollDice(6, num);
                                ep += randNum;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            for (int j = 0; j < entry.Value[i]; j++)
                            {
                                int randNum = RollDice(6, num);
                                pp += randNum;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[5] { cp, sp, gp, ep, pp };
    return result;
}

private void TreasureResults(int[] results)
{
    int cp = results[0];
    int sp = results[1];
    int gp = results[2];
    int ep = results[3];
    int pp = results[4];
    lbl_cp_amount.Text = cp.ToString();
    lbl_sp_amount.Text = sp.ToString();
    lbl_gp_amount.Text = gp.ToString();
    lbl_ep_amount.Text = ep.ToString();
    lbl_pp_amount.Text = pp.ToString();
}
```

The button click is linked to a form button so it is only being called once. The results I'm getting should be:

If d100 <= the dictionary key, loop through the values and find any value over 0 and do that many random rolls.

When I press the button, the code is behaving as if it's running through all of the keys, and returning multiple results.

Comment: Debug your code. If you don't know how, learn now. You need to step through the code and compare what it actually does to what you expect it to do AT EVERY STEP. If you want our help, you need to explain the logic you're trying to implement and explain exactly where and how the code behaves other than you expect.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say you get multiple results. Do you mean different kinds of coins or you're getting multiple values flashing in the coin texts? If the latter I would assume you've subscribed the challenge1_Click callback too many times, but you haven't posted how you do that.

Comment: My apologies guys, I added this after attempting to work on it for almost 26hrs straight. I should have slept and checked again before jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While checking if the d100 was less than or equal to the entry.Key, I wasn't checking to make sure that it wasn't larger than the previous key also. So if it was less than the first key, it was also then less than they rest of the keys so I had to add in the following:

```
int previousKey = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int[]> entry in weights)
        {
            int knownKey = entry.Key;
            if (d100 <= knownKey && d100 > previousKey)
            {
                previousKey = entry.Key;
```

My apologies to those that read this and got extremely confused.